# something like an onkeydown event trigger but in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, eventtrigger

I know you can trigger a Google Apps Script with onEdit or onChange. For instance in Google Sheets onEdit will trigger when the user hits enter or leaves a cell.

What I want is a way to do something like the onkeydown or onkeypress event that exists in Javascript, such that the Google Apps script is triggered when the user merely types a new letter into a cell, without hitting enter or leaving the cell.

Does this exist?

Comment: You could do that with htmlService using  a dialog or sidebar and perhaps google.script.run performing the access to google services

Comment: In addition to what @Cooper said, unfortunately, GAS does not support client-side events but you can create custom functions in sheets add-on that can be triggered by a keyboard shortcut.